# Syntax differences between mysql, sqlite and pgsql

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, postgresql, pdo

I'm creating a tiny activerecord library using PDO and I'm planning to support **MySQL**, **Sqlite** and **PgSQL**.

My question is how I can be sure that the query string works with all adapters? There will mostly be CRUD statements with some joins etc. Is there a standard I can follow that works for all of these?

Thanks 
/ Tobias

**EDIT:** Thanks for all your answers but my question was more about the SQL '**syntax**' differences between them.

Comment: sure. you can always have a possibility to tie your hands up and make a miserable sqlite out of powerful Postgre.

Comment: The problem with this kind of approach is that the resulting application will run equally slow on all platforms - especially if it's a non-trivial application. I would rather try to do the abstraction on the business layer and exploit DBMS specific features wherever you can in the the data access layer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: for stuffs like this, I'd always respond, show me a performance problem, then I'd use switch to running regular query. Worrying about performance because of the database abstraction layer seems to me to be a premature optimization; and even when using an abstraction layer I always have the option to run regular queries.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write your own DB layer, I'd suggest you:

1. Use placeholders, if you aren't already. They add security too.
2. Use bindParam/bindValue with value type (e.g. BOOLEANS don't exist in SQLite but work if bound with PARAM_BOOL)...
3. Use stored procedures from MySQL, create matching names in PostgreSQL, and define them in SQLite with sqliteCreateAggregate/sqliteCreateFunction.
4. Do all parameter checking in PHP, because SQLite won't do any (e.g. validate date variables)...
5. Use InnoDB for MySQL to get transactions.

**Note:** By supporting these vastly different RDBMs, you're demoting the database to just a data store. Keep in mind that SQLite is very limited. It does not have native data types save from number/string. E.g. it's missing date handling and intervals, and so on. All three databases support transactions, which are essential for data integrity when the integrity is maintained outside the DB.

**Edit:** Removed mention of MySQL triggers, which are availabe for 5.0.

Comment: As much as I prefer Postgres: MySQL **does** have triggers. But foreign keys are much better suited to to ensure data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html) you have a simple introduction to zend_db_adapter - i think you want something similar (I posted this just as a example to see how others resolve the problem you have)

Answer (score 0):

My choice for this kind of issues would be [ADOdb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/). While I never actually used it with PostgreSQL, it just saved my sanity in a project that happened to be born with MySQL and then migrated to SQL Server, to SQLite and back to SQL Server.